# xamarin.ios receive notification when app is in background

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios

How can I handle notifications if my App in in Background and incative ?
Now, I get an Alert, which opens my App, when I tap on it.
But when the Notification receives I want to handle the ApplicationIconBadgeNumber.

Which method listen to notifications when my App is in Background?

HEres my AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            PushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            PushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);
        }

public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            PushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to handle the ApplicationIconBadgeNumber in background without tapping on notification?

Comment: Yes, thats right.
When I receive an message and Im in debug Modus, my App is in Background, the BadgeNumber increase.
If Im not in Debug-Modus and I receive an notifitcation, the BadgeNumber doesnt increase, because my App is not active.

Whats the solution ?

Comment: No , it is not possible .`DidReceiveRemoteNotification` is triggered only after we tap on the notification.

Comment: But how did Whats app deal with this ?
If I Close whats app and get a Message, the IconBadgeNumber increases

Answer (score 1):

Actually apple push notification are handled by iOS and not your app. We can't change the badge on receiving a push notification. DidReceiveRemoteNotification is triggred  only if user tap on the notification. so updating badge number in this method is not wise.

We can alter the badge number when we are in the background state by sending the "badge" parameter in the push notification package.

Sample payload:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "message",
        "badge" : 2
    }
}
```

your app icon will show 2. Here the point is that calculation for badge count should be done in the server side.

Note that the badge parameter in the payload must be an integer.